# Multi dynamic rows into multi column MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I'm using MySQL. I have to separate multi repeated rows into columns. The table has following structure.

[image: The table has following structure.]

But I need like this.

[image]

**Note: There will be always 6 records of each *DateTime*. But *Title* and *Feedback* are dynamic.** I tried to use

`select DateTime,`

But this is not giving my expected value. I wrote a code (not considered about title):

```
select 
    g.dateTime AS dateTime,
    g.feedback as feedback ,
    c.title AS title    
from gauge g
inner join category c on g.category_id=c.category_id AND c.title ='title' AND g.feedback ='feedback' 
group by g.dateTime
```

This doesn't work and I tried `GROUP_CONCAT(.... SEPARATOR'.....' )` this gives me not expected output, just gives output in one column. My approach might be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Use a dynamic pivot since there are many different values

[Fiddle to play with](http://rextester.com/HWB47066)

```
drop table t;
create table t
(
  dateTime datetime,
  title varchar(50),
  feedback int
);

insert into t values
( '2018-06-29 12:55:36', 'A', 1),
( '2018-06-29 12:55:36', 'B', 2),
( '2018-06-22 12:55:36', 'A', 1),
( '2018-06-22 12:55:36', 'B', 2),
( '2018-06-22 12:55:36', 'C', 3);

SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'MAX(CASE WHEN title = ''',
      title,
      ''' THEN ''', title ,''' END) AS ',
      CONCAT(' Title',title,',')
    ),
     CONCAT(
      'MAX(CASE WHEN feedback = ''',
      feedback,
      ''' THEN ''', feedback ,''' END) AS ',
      CONCAT(' Feedback',feedback)
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM T;


SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT dateTime, ', @sql, ' 
                   FROM t
                   GROUP BY dateTime');


PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Comment: hi this is working in sql, Im not good with pivot. How can I add joins here as I mentioned

Comment: please let me know

Answer (score 0):

I would simply use conditional aggregation.  Enumerating the values is a bit tricky in MySQL (unless you are using MySQL 8+):

```
select datetime,
       max(case when rn = 1 then title end) as title_1,
       max(case when rn = 1 then feedback end) as feedback_1,
       max(case when rn = 2 then title end) as title_2,
       max(case when rn = 2 then feedback end) as feedback_2,
       max(case when rn = 3 then title end) as title_3,
       max(case when rn = 3 then feedback end) as feedback_3,
       max(case when rn = 4 then title end) as title_4,
       max(case when rn = 4 then feedback end) as feedback_4,
       max(case when rn = 5 then title end) as title_5,
       max(case when rn = 5 then feedback end) as feedback_5,
       max(case when rn = 6 then title end) as title_6,
       max(case when rn = 6 then feedback end) as feedback_6
from (select gc.*,
             (@rn := if(@dt = g.dateTime, @rn + 1,
                        if(@dt := g.dateTime, 1, 1)
                       )
             ) as rn
      from (select g.dateTime, g.feedback, c.title AS title    
            from gauge g inner join
                 category c
                 on g.category_id = c.category_id and
                    c.title = 'title' and
                    g.feedback = 'feedback' 
            group by g.dateTime
            order by g.dateTime
           ) gc cross join
           (select @dt := '', @rn := 0) params
     ) gc
group by datetime;
```

I don't think the filtering on `c.title` and `g.feedback` is correct.

Comment: @varman Debugging code is part of programmers job.  If error message says `dt` unknown, then search it and figure out why it's unknown.

Answer (score -1):

Not an optimized approach but you may join them into table and filter according to row number modulo by 6. This way, we can separate the 6 rows into 6 different table

http://rextester.com/DLVV64095

```
SELECT MAIN.DateTime,
    TBL1.TITLE AS Title1,
    TBL1.FEEDBACK AS Feedback1,
    TBL2.TITLE AS Title2,
    TBL2.FEEDBACK AS Feedback2,
    TBL3.TITLE AS Title3,
    TBL3.FEEDBACK AS Feedback3,
    TBL4.TITLE AS Title4,
    TBL4.FEEDBACK AS Feedback4,
    TBL5.TITLE AS Title5,
    TBL5.FEEDBACK AS Feedback5,
    TBL6.TITLE AS Title6,
    TBL6.FEEDBACK AS Feedback6
FROM (
    SELECT [DATETIME] AS [DateTime]
    FROM GAUGE
    GROUP BY [DATETIME]
) MAIN
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT G.DATETIME,
        G.FEEDBACK,
        C.TITLE,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ORDER BY (SELECT 1) ASC) AS ROWNO
    FROM GAUGE G
    INNER JOIN CATEGORY C
        ON G.CATEGORY_ID = C.CATEGORY_ID
) TBL1
    ON TBL1.DATETIME = MAIN.[DateTime]
    AND TBL1.ROWNO % 6 = 1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT G.DATETIME,
        G.FEEDBACK,
        C.TITLE,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ORDER BY (SELECT 1) ASC) AS ROWNO
    FROM GAUGE G
    INNER JOIN CATEGORY C
        ON G.CATEGORY_ID = C.CATEGORY_ID
) TBL2
    ON TBL2.DATETIME = MAIN.[DateTime]
    AND TBL2.ROWNO % 6 = 2
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT G.DATETIME,
        G.FEEDBACK,
        C.TITLE,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ORDER BY (SELECT 1) ASC) AS ROWNO
    FROM GAUGE G
    INNER JOIN CATEGORY C
        ON G.CATEGORY_ID = C.CATEGORY_ID
) TBL3
    ON TBL3.DATETIME = MAIN.[DateTime]
    AND TBL3.ROWNO % 6 = 3
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT G.DATETIME,
        G.FEEDBACK,
        C.TITLE,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ORDER BY (SELECT 1) ASC) AS ROWNO
    FROM GAUGE G
    INNER JOIN CATEGORY C
        ON G.CATEGORY_ID = C.CATEGORY_ID
) TBL4
    ON TBL4.DATETIME = MAIN.[DateTime]
    AND TBL4.ROWNO % 6 = 4
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT G.DATETIME,
        G.FEEDBACK,
        C.TITLE,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ORDER BY (SELECT 1) ASC) AS ROWNO
    FROM GAUGE G
    INNER JOIN CATEGORY C
        ON G.CATEGORY_ID = C.CATEGORY_ID
) TBL5
    ON TBL5.DATETIME = MAIN.[DateTime]
    AND TBL5.ROWNO % 6 = 5
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT G.DATETIME,
        G.FEEDBACK,
        C.TITLE,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ORDER BY (SELECT 1) ASC) AS ROWNO
    FROM GAUGE G
    INNER JOIN CATEGORY C
        ON G.CATEGORY_ID = C.CATEGORY_ID
) TBL6
    ON TBL6.DATETIME = MAIN.[DateTime]
    AND TBL6.ROWNO % 6 = 0
```

Comment: I mentioned mysql, oopz